# Where should commit/build data be stored?

Tags: kiwi-tcms

Question: What is the best way to save the Git commit ID for a Test Run?

Details:

I'm integrating GitLab -> SoapUI -> Kiwi by using the JSON-RPC API.
I'm creating new Test Runs for each Regression run kicked off by a Git commit.
I want to save the Git commit ID in each Test Run.

It looked like Product Version would serve this purpose. However, when I create a new Version (or re-use an existing one) and then include the product_version_id in the TestRun.create call, the version is not being associated with the Test Run.

Here's some of that code:

```
testRunCreateString = {
    'build': buildID,
    'manager': 2,
    'plan': 22,
    'summary': 'Running Regression Suite',
    'product_version_id': version,
    }

response = client.send(Request("TestRun.create", values=testRunCreateString))
```

I see in the code for the TestRun class that product_version may soon be deprecated for TestRun:

```
class TestRun(TCMSActionModel):
    history = KiwiHistoricalRecords()

    # todo: this field should be removed in favor of plan.product_version
    # no longer shown in edit forms
```

So if product_version is/will be stored on a Test Plan basis, and I don't want to create new test plans for every regression run, what's the best way to save Git commit ID data for each run?

Update:

I see that there are no product_* fields on testruns_testrun or testrun_testexecution, only on testplans_testplan. I don't want a whole new plan for every regression test - there could be hundreds for each project and they'd be meaningless in that quantity.

I could add a link to the Gitlab commit (CI_REPOSITORY_URL/commit/CI_COMMIT_SHA) to the test execution when I add the results.

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your original question:

all of our test framework plugins assume that the commit sha represents a build number b/c every commit is essentially a slightly different variant of the product. Maybe going towards the next version.  In these same plugins branch name and/or pull request number is considered a Version b/c you can have multiple rebuilds/pushes before you get things right.  You can search for TP/TR on https://tcms.kiwitcms.org (search is public) to see this in action.

That being said it is up to you to figure out what sort of granularity you want to use and how exactly you are going to consume this information. If you have multiple product versions (even though they may not be supported in parallel) it does make sense to have commit==build relationship. If you don't care about the individual commits then add this info as notes or skip it entirely.

> I see that there are no product_* fields on testruns_testrun or testrun_testexecution, only on testplans_testplan. I don't want a whole new plan for every regression test - there could be hundreds for each project and they'd be meaningless in that quantity.

Right, TestExecution and TestRun objects know only about Builds, see the picture here:
https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/introduction.html#data-organization-within-kiwi-tcms and also here 
https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/db.html

So you can have 1 TP for each Product, and then create new TRs for each commit/build/timestamp. You can set Version to 1.0 (master or whatever) and then use the Build field to represent the commit information. You can also add this into TR.summary as a prefix or add it into notes, comments, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be using the Build field to store the build info! ;)